# Making strncmp() accept unsigned char * as an argument

Tags: c++, c

I have a pointer to a string which is "unsigned char *" and i want to use it as an argument in strncmp() function.
But compiler complains:

```
invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'const char*'
```

How can i make:

```
strncmp(const char *a, unsigned char *b, size_t size);
```

work?

Is there any workaround?

Comment: you need to provide more context (ie code)

Comment: Why is your string `unsigned char`?

Comment: strncmp() accepts arg 1 and arg 2 as const char *. But argument 2 i have is of type 'unsigned char * ' and argument 1 is ' const char * '. How can i make the function work with my arguments?

Comment: You don't have to re-iterate your question. We wish to know *more* details, not just the same ones.

Comment: @StoryTeller not unsigned char but unsigned char *

Comment: The character type of you "string" is `unsigned char`. Why?

Comment: @StoryTeller isn't the question simple enough? Do you need more details? That is the requirement in my code.

Comment: I just said I need more details. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @tinga taking the leap that you know what you're doing and this isn't an XY problem, cast as-appropriate to the actual language you're using. I suspect you already knew that, however.

Comment: are you trying to compile C code using C++ compiler?

Comment: If `char` is signed, what do you want to happen with an `unsigned char` value that won't fit in a signed `char` type? That's the decision you have to make before you decide that a cast, possibly leading to undefined behavior, is the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely cast unsigned into signed.

```
 unsigned char * p2 = ...;
 strncmp(px, (char *)p2, 5);
```

should work.

```
 unsigned char * p2 = ...;
 char * p3 = static_cast<char *>(p2);
```

This maybe overkill.

Comment: Not an issue of signed or unsigned. Issue of const vs non-const

Comment: @tinga Curious, have you tried this answer?  I'd expect the issue to be a pointer to signed vs. unsigned one.

Comment: Um, no. If `char` is signed, pretending that those unsigned values are actually signed values produces undefined behavior. For example, if the underlying code simply treats the unsigned bit patterns as signed values, the effect is that large positive values become negative, and comparisons involving those values can come out backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using `unsigned char*`, but if you need to, use a cast. For example :

`strncmp(a, (char*)b, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

use reinterpret_cast to convert it. Something like this  -

```
strncmp(const char *a, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(unsigned char
 *b), size_t size);
```